# A thin line between native wordpress bahaviour and 3rd party themes

Tags: themes, core, third-party-applications

Bear with me as i try to learn WP.

Lets say we have a 3rd party theme were the route of the request is somehow like this.

Root theme index.php diverts to a nother php file which decides what page to go next depending on the themes settings.

then it gets diverted to a master page that handles all kind of pages (posts,pages,archives) using logic within this file.

And now Native WordPress comes and says for example that you can just create a category-{slug}.php file and use it.

It seems to work this way if i put a simple category-{slug}.php in my themes ROOT directory.

So is this how everything is working in WP? I can make a child theme for my paid theme and go inside and everything that codex says?

Maybe i am not well understood , but if someone "catches" my thinking , i would appreciate a shed of light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rely on the codex. Some pages are just a heap of crap and totally useless. The problem with the codex is that everybody with an account on wordpress.org can change and alter the codex as they see fit.

I don't say,  *Do not use the codex*,  I'm saying that you need to be cautious. You need to read the codex in conjuction with the actual source code. Some pages are very well written and clear with many good examples of usage.

The way I read your question, you are hinting on the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). This is one of the most important section as this is how Wordpress decides which template to serve up according to the URL been served. These templates are the recommended ones and any template naming convention outside this hierarchy won't work out of the box. Also, any naming convention that creates conflict with these set hierarchy will be ignored and will fail.

There are filters like `template_include` and `single-template` which will allow you to set a custom template which is outside normal hierarchy rules according to your needs. For example, if you need a custom template for the single posts of a specific category, you can create a file called `single-cat.php` and then use the `single_template` filter to tell Wordpress to use this template whenever a single post is from this specific category

### EDIT

From comments, it is really easy to create any template in your theme. `index.php` can used as a base for any template. You just need to make a copy of `index.php` and rename it to what is needed

For eaxample, if your theme don't have a category.php, you can simply copy `index.php` and rename it to `category.php`

Comment: Quite there. In the hierarchy says about front-page.php. there is no such page anywhere in my WP installation. Instead there is an index.php in all themes root dir...This is the starting point?

Comment: @e4rthdog from Template Hierarchy: "With the exception of the basic index.php template file, Theme developers can choose whether they want to implement a particular template file or not. If WordPress cannot find a template file with a matching name, it skips down to the next file name in the hierarchy. If WordPress cannot find any matching template file, index.php (the Theme's home page template file) will be used." index.php is the only *required* template for a valid theme, all others are optional.

Comment: `front-page.php` is a page you have to create if needed. This template is very rarely included in themes. This template is used when you set a static front page. Usually most people will just use page.php or any custom page template

Comment: Missed that, sorry..So my 3rd party dev chose the last option and made everything else as his own. So, i have all the "above" options at my disposal and i will catch it before it goes to my 3rd party dev files. Its my choice if i want to duplicate 3rd party logic or not to a category-{slug}.php file. Correct?

Comment: @Milo thanks for that extra info. You should actually post that as a separate answer :-)

Comment: Just a tip, to create any template in a theme, simply copy your index.php and rename it accordingly. If your theme does not have a front-page.php, copy index.php and rename it front-page.php. Thats all

Comment: My current template index.php has just a require..you will have to "follow" to find the lowest level of .php file and take that becuase that is actually the index.php you are looking for..Put that comment in the answer. I think that this is clearing things up

Comment: Themes and plugins are just a means to create a visual presentation which is functional and usable within the scope set out by the user. Wordpress provides the basic platform with functionality and this platform can be extended or modified as you see fit through various functions, filters and hooks within the scope Wordpress, PHP, HTML and CSS.

Comment: Done, answer updated. I hope this helped in clearing things up for you :-)